# Manifest Merger Failed in Android Studio after downloading adview

Tags: java, android, adview

Error:
**Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0] C:\Users\HP.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e81645b3d583edffedf2649e74819131\jetified-play-services-ads-19.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15**

This error did not come before downloading *Ad view*.

Comment: update your minSdkVersion 16 from your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

As the error message notes, this library does not work on API 15 (your `minSdkVersion`).

As API 14/15 support was [dropped in version 19.0.0](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes), you'll have to either update your `minSdkVersion` to at least 16 (the officially recommended approach), or use version `18.3.0` of any Play Services dependencies if you wish to continue supporting those devices.  See [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html) for more detailed advice, as well as an additional alternative involving distributing multiple versions of your app.